# Connection error to Azure SQL Database when running .Net Core console app as Azure webjob

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs, webjob

I have .Net Core console app that connects to Azure SQL database using entity framework.
Every think works fine locally but when I created publish package using this command line

> dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained false

Zipped it and upload it and used it in Azure webjob I get this exception in the job output:

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'myDB' on server 'tcp:myServer.database.windows.net,1433'.
>
> [03/13/2019 19:10:11 > 62ab86: INFO] System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

I added this section to the .json file but it didn't help

```
"runtimes": {
"win7-x64": {},
"win10-x64": {}
}
```

Comment: That error message is a definite pointer to "I am a 64-bit process trying to load a 32-bit assembly" (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, when an .NET Core project is migrated to the csproj format, there are certain conditions under which the resulting csproj will not receive an explicit `<PlatformTarget>`.

And Visual Studio doesn't seem to behave identically when doing a usual build vs. publishing.

In both bases, it will build an PE32 executable with 32-bits only. But when publishing, it will deploy 64-bit libraries alongside, leading to the aforementioned `BadImageFormatException`, while **it doesn't do that in a non-publish build**.

Solution:

In the `project>Properties>Build` page, select the `platform target` to x64. Event if it doesn't have any visual effect, an explicit  will be added to the csproj on save.

```
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

Comment: This led to different error in the output
`"Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\FrameworkDependantJob\cryxsmtr.4lv\publish\myProject.dll'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Comment: .NET Core versions 2.2.0 and 2.2.1 are being rolled out as of now and support x64. If you’re running your ASP.NET Core application on .NET Core 2.2 with in-process hosting, you can simply [enable the 64-bit option in the Azure Portal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-2-available-today/) and the site will now run in a 64-bit process.